# Getting invalid RFC3339Nano error while deleting from InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-go

i am new in influxDB, i want to delete some data from influxDB from postman. I am using below query from postman

```
"data":{    
    "start": "2021-01-09T12:00:00Z",
    "stop": "2021-01-09T12:00:00Z",
    "predicate": "_measurement=\"mymesurement\""
  }
  }
```

**Also provided the Authorization token and content-type in the header**

But when i executed the command it is giving me below error

```
{
    "code": "invalid",
    "message": "invalid request; error parsing request json: invalid RFC3339Nano for field start, please format your time with RFC3339Nano format, example: 2009-01-02T23:00:00Z"
}
```

Also tried in CLI but still getting the same error.

```
influx delete 
 --bucket 'mybucket'\
 --org 'myorg' \
 --token 'mytoken'
 --start '2009-01-02T00:00:00.001Z' \
 --stop '2009-01-02TT00:00:00.001Z' \
 --predicate '_measurement=mymesurement'
```

Kindly help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried passing the nanoseconds even if they are `0`? `--start '2009-01-02T00:00:00.000000000Z'`

Comment: Thanks Jim for the quick response. I tried but even after it is giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to update both start and stop field to follow either RFC3339 or RFC3339Nano standard according to InfluxDB's Golang convention [here](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants). That is, RFC3339 = **"2021-01-09T12:00:00Z00:00"**  (4 more digits after the "Z") or RFC3339Nano = **"2021-01-09T12:00:00.000000000Z00:00"** (9 more digits after the decimal point and before the "Z", plus 4 more digits after the "Z") .

InfluxDB support both format according to [its original code](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/2e9e174c2453794ecab08ffa603ed16254679a9f/http/delete_handler.go#L202) and [its docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/write-data/delete-data/#delete-data-using-the-influx-cli).

P.S.: You'd better make the stop field different from the start one. Otherwise, there won't be any data deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I tried to do it through command line.
But on Postman it worked for me.

Below is a sample based on my original request:-

POST Request
`http://localhost:8086/api/v2/delete?org=MySampleOrg&bucket=MySampleBucket`

Headers

```
Authorization:Token MY_PRIVATE_TOKEN
Content-Type:application/json
```

Body

```
{
    "start": "2023-12-06T00:00:00Z",
    "stop": "2023-12-07T23:00:00Z",
    "predicate": "_measurement=\"sampleMeasurement\" AND sampleTag=\"SAMPLE111\""
}
```

This returned an empty response with status code `204`. To confirm I ran `select` query and found that particular entry was deleted successfully.